# How to sync view with model changes / rerender

Tags: java, wicket

I have a form that contains a text field input that is bound to a field in a model object. When a user enters data into that text field it can affect multiple other fields/components within the form based on calculations. My business logic is encapsulated in a service layer.

Theoretically the way I want this to work is that when the user updates the field, an ajax call is made to the server (on keypress) where the logic from the service is applied and all affected fields are updated on the model object. Once the model has been updated on the server, I want to sync the current state of the model object to the screen.

Is the only way to do this to refresh the entire screen? Is there a way to re-render only the components bound to the fields in the model that have changed? Also, if I refresh the screen, the field that is being edited is updated as well, is there a way to exclude this?

I am interested in any best practices for this technique.

Thanks

Comment: The best practice is to use Javascript that is called from AJAX response callback to update the fields.

Answer (score 1):

With Ajax you can update any Component you want, just make sure it has markup id (`Component.setOutputMarkupId(true)`).

You need to use `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` or `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` and in its `onUpdate()` callback you have to update the models of the respective `FormComponent`s and then you can use `FormComponent.this.getForm().visitChildren(FormComponent.class, IVisit)` to visit all FormComponents of the current Form and add to AjaxRequestTarget only the ones you have updated.

**Update**
Another good solution (even better!) is to use Wicket Event bus. In the Ajax behavior you could broadcast an event:

```
component.send(getForm(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new UIChangedEvent(target, newValue));
```

where `UIChangedEvent` is your own class/POJO that brings the new value of the updated component and the AjaxRequestTarget.

Then the other FormComponents could override `#onEvent()` and use the value to calculate their new value and use the target to update themselves or not, depending on the earlier calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin, What I would really like is to have the view rerender, but only those fields that have values that are different than what is on the screen currently, without having to explicitly create dependencies by adding behaviors like "onupdate change field A, B, C, F, X". If you are suggesting only adding to the ones that are updated, is there a way to determine via wicket which fields are updated? Or do you have to have a reference to the original model and do a comparison field by field?

Comment: Hi Martin, personally I dislike events carrying new values. I think they should be set on the appropriate models by the components theirselves. The event should be processed by the components working on the model (or derivative models), these components then re-use the data in the model. This prevents the 'who is responsible for updating the models' bugs

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your tags that you're using wicket. Wicket uses Behaviors for this purpose. In the following example you will update both DropDownChoices if the input of the TextField changed. You just need to add those controls to the AjaxRequestTarget. Models of both DropDownChoices will be reloaded and rerendered at the frontend. Also make sure to call setOutputMarkupId(true) on controls you want to update.

```
    TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("input");
    Component dropDownA = new DropDownChoice<>("dropA").setOutputMarkupId(true);
    Component dropDownB = new DropDownChoice<>("dropB").setOutputMarkupId(true);

    textField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1478280524536023725L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(dropDownA);
            target.add(dropDownB);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The event type should be specified without the `on` prefix. So in this case it's just `change` instead of `onchange`. See following warning from `AjaxEventBehavior` in Wicket 7: "Since version 6.0.0 Wicket uses JavaScript event registration so there is no need of the leading 'on' in the event name '%s'. Please use just '%s'. Wicket 8.x won't manipulate the provided event names so the leading 'on' may break your application."

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wasn't aware about that and changed the regarding statement.